# Opinions/Improvements on a run periodically/timer function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, random, timer, python-2.x

I'm looking for some opinions on this bit of code that I wrote and if there are any ways it can be improved.

The scripts aim is to run the function runme() every 60 seconds with a random interval anywhere between -20 seconds to +40 seconds so it could run randomly anywhere between 40 seconds and 100 seconds.

```
import sched, time
import random

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def periodically(runtime, intsmall, intlarge, function):
    runtime += random.randrange(intsmall, intlarge)
    s.enter(runtime, 1, function, ())
    s.run()

def runme():
    print "hi"

while True:
    periodically(60, -20, +40, runme)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you do need the scheduler for that, at least not for how you use it.
Your loop schedules 1 event and just afterwards waits until it's finished, since run() waits until the scheduled event(s) are completed.

You can achieve the same by just sleeping for `runtime` seconds and calling `runme()` afterwards (you have to sleep before, since the scheduler delays the action for `runtime` seconds).

Also note that `random.randrange(intsmall, intlarge)` will return a value between `intsmall` and `intlarge - 1`, so your random time will be between 40 seconds and 99 seconds.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. I don't quite understand are you saying that s.run and s.enter are the wrong way round?

I want to avoid: `def periodically(runtime, intsmall, intlarge):
    runtime += random.randrange(intsmall, intlarge)
    sleep(runtime)
    runme()`

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not saying that `s.run()` and `s.enter()` are the wrong way round - they are fine as written. But if you replace them with `sleep()` and `runme()`, that sequence should be changed. The scheduler delays first and then runs, so you need the sleep before the run, if not using the scheduler but just sleeping and running.